# Скрыть вывод команды ping

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

Есть фрагмент кода:

```py
import os
address = 'google.com'
response = os.system('ping -c 1 ' + address)
```

Проблема в том, что бесполезная в моём случае информация, выводимая командой `ping`, не должна выводиться в консоль.

Comment: Используй execv или subprocess

Comment: судя по -с вы запускаетесь не с винды. Тогда `ping -c 1 avito.ru &>/dev/null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

через subprocess

```py
import subprocess
response = subprocess.check_output(
        ['ping', '-c', '1', address],
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
        universal_newlines=True  
    )
```

переменная `response` будет содержать инфу по ping

**UPD**

[Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

Буквально перевод

> Выполняет команду с аргументами и возвращает вывод

Comment: exit code достаточно обычно. Например в своих проектах так делаю

Comment: А что за инфу будет содержать?

Comment: @R1senDev дополнил ответ на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 3):

если требуется получать только код завершения ping, то можно перенаправить вывод в '> nul'

```
os.system(f'ping {address} > nul')
```

Answer (score 1):

`pip install ping3`

```py
from ping3 import ping

if ping('avito.ru', timeout=1) is not None:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('fail')

if ping('yandex.ru', timeout=1) is not None:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('fail')
```

---

```latex
fail
ok
```

[ping3](https://pypi.org/project/ping3/)

> Есть нюанс. В Windows параметр количества запросов  это -n.
> посему, если следовать принципу универсальности (во загнул )
> IMHO лучше всего использовать специальный инструмент.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно у меня (на Linux) помогло перенаправление потока вывода:

```py
import os
address = 'google.com'
response = os.system('ping -c 1 ' + address + ' &> dev/null/')
```